# I don't know how to use memcmp in c++

Tags: c++

I wonder when I execute this program why this result is that

```
int arr[4][4] = { 0,0,1,1,
                  1,1,1,1,
                  0,1,1,0,      
                  1,1,1,1 
                } ;

int arr2[2][2] = {1};

cout << memcmp(arr, arr2, 4) << endl ;
cout << memcmp(arr+1, arr2, 4) << endl ;
cout << memcmp(arr+2, arr2, 4) << endl ;
cout << memcmp(arr+3, arr2, 4) << endl ;
```

result is

```
-1
0
-1
0
```

how do comapre arr and arr2 ?

I wonder why result is (-1 0 -1 0 ).

please.

Comment: In most cases I write `memcmp` as `std::equal` in C++.

Comment: "I don't know how to use `memcmp` in C++": are you bragging? <g>

Answer (score 1):

`memcmp`'s 3rd parameter should be `4*sizeof(int)`

`memcmp` takes two `void*` and will not know the width of the type, it always compare as if the pointer is `unsigned char*`, so what you compare is the first 4 byte (not 4 `int`) point by the two pointer

Anyway, you will have some problem on endianness if you do this. I will suggest use some compare function that take the type into concern.

Comment: byte is not a type, but it still compare on byte unit, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, it's too early in the morning. That's pretty much what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of memcmp is

```
 int memcmp ( const void * ptr1, const void * ptr2, size_t num );
```

It compares the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr1 to the first num bytes pointed by ptr2, returning zero if they all match or a value different from zero representing which is greater if they do not.

**condition 1**

the output of memcmp will be **<0** if the first byte that does not match in both memory blocks has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2

**condition 2**

the output of memcmp will be **0** if the contents of both memory blocks are equal and

**condition 3**

the output will be >0 if  the first byte that does not match in both memory blocks has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2

here is the simple program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

     int main ()
     {
     char buffer1[] = "NEpAL";
     char buffer2[] = "NEPAL";

      int n;

     n=memcmp ( buffer1, buffer2, sizeof(buffer1) );

     if (n>0) printf ("'%s' is greater than '%s'.\n",buffer1,buffer2);
     else if (n<0) printf ("'%s' is less than '%s'.\n",buffer1,buffer2);
     else printf ("'%s' is the same as '%s'.\n",buffer1,buffer2);

      return 0;
      }
```

the output will be

'NEpAL' is greater than 'NEPAL'.

as p = 112 and P=80 . Hope it helps